# How to create service in angular js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, onsen-ui

This is my code which is using service in angular.js.If i run this code 
I am getting this error Uncaught Error: [ng:areq].

```
</ons-toolbar>
        <div ng-controller="testAppController">
          Search: <input ng-model="query" type="text" class="text-input" id="my-input"/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:query">
        <td>{{country.name}}</td>
        <td>{{country.population}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </div>

 <div ng-include='"partials/footer.html"'></div>
    </ons-page>
```

demo.js

```
angular.module('testsapp',[])
  .service('helloworldservice',function($http){
     this.getDatafunction = function(){
        $http.get('json/countries.json')
          .success(function(data) {
             alert("sucesss");
          })
          .error(function(data) {
            alert("wrong");
          });     
     }
  })
  .controller('testAppController',['helloworldservice',function($scope,helloworldservice){
     helloworldservice.getDatafunction();
  }]);
```

Comment: Can you put the whole error?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10-build.2143+sha.6a9ccac/ng/areq?p0=testAppController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: where did u put the ng-app?

Comment: Is ng-app directive anywhere in your html?

Comment: I added like this <ons-page ng-app="testsapp">

Comment: You're declaring your dependencies wrong, `['helloworldservice',function($scope,helloworldservice)` should be  `['$scope', 'helloworldservice', function($scope,helloworldservice)`

Comment: you need to declare $scope in the square brackets before the function initialisation in your controller

Answer (score 1):

here

```
 .controller('testAppController',['helloworldservice',function($scope,helloworldservice)
```

you need to change to

```
.controller('testAppController',['$scope','helloworldservice',function($scope,helloworldservice)
```

please read more here

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification

```js
angular.module('testsapp', []).service('helloworldservice', function($http) {
  this.getDatafunction = function() {
    $http.get('json/countries.json').
    success(function(data) {
      alert("sucesss");
    }).
    error(function(data) {
      alert("wrong");
    });
  }

}).controller('testAppController', ['$scope','helloworldservice',
  function($scope, helloworldservice) {
    
    helloworldservice.getDatafunction();
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <body ng-app="testsapp">

        <div ng-controller="testAppController">
          Search: <input ng-model="query" type="text" class="text-input" id="my-input"/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries | filter:query">
        <td>{{country.name}}</td>
        <td>{{country.population}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </div>

 <div ng-include='"partials/footer.html"'></div>
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the $scope service name in the controller definition:

```
.controller('testAppController',['$scope', 'helloworldservice',function($scope,helloworldservice){
   helloworldservice.getDatafunction();
}]);
```

Remember that if you specify the service names as strings for the parameters, you have to specify all the parameters for the function. Specifying the services names for injection is a recommended practice [when you will minify the javascript](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification).

Taking this into account, could be good to do the same for the $http parameter in your service definition:

```
.service('helloworldservice',['$http', function($http){
  this.getDatafunction = function(){
    $http.get('json/countries.json')
      .success(function(data) {
         alert("sucesss");
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        alert("wrong");
      });     
  }
}])
```